# Eigen compilation warning for 4x4 matrix inverse at InverseSize4.h

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I have the following code using eigen3 (v3.4) library:

```
Eigen::Matrix4d m;
Eigen::Vector4d v;
Eigen::Vector4d r = m.inverse() * v;
```

leading to a compilation warning for MSVC VS2019 (dunno if it's only VS issue).

The warnings I've got are popping up in `InverseSize4.h` of eigen library:

```
Eigen\src/LU/arch/InverseSize4.h(326,1): warning C4838: conversion from 'unsigned long' to 'const int' requires a narrowing conversion
Eigen\src/LU/arch/InverseSize4.h(327,1): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
Eigen\src/LU/arch/InverseSize4.h(327,1): warning C4838: conversion from 'unsigned long' to 'const int' requires a narrowing conversion
```

appropriate code-snippet of InverseSize4.h

```
const int bits1[4] = {0, -2147483648, 0, 0};
const int bits2[4] = {0, 0, 0, -2147483648};
```

I don't really understand why the number is actually treated as unsigned long.

If I replace everything by 3 dimensional stuff I got no warnings.

`static_casts` or `LL` suffix seem to fix the issue, but not sure if it is the right thing to do.

```
const int bits1[4] = {0, -static_cast<int64_t>(2147483648), 0, 0};
const int bits2[4] = {0, 0, 0, -static_cast<int64_t>(2147483648)};

const int bits1[4] = {0, -2147483648LL, 0, 0};
const int bits2[4] = {0, 0, 0, -2147483648LL};
```

Has anybody an idea what I'm doing wrong or if it is a "bug" in eigen? As eigen is header only and I'm using high warning level combined with treat warning as error, I need to somehow fix this.

Thanks for help!

Comment: As per the duplicate I found, this appears to be a bug with MSVC. You may still report this to Eigen, we could workaround this (or mask away the warning). Please link to this SO post for reference.

Comment: @chtz: I opened a bug report on gitlab eigen project